# What is wrong with this extremely simple numpy script?

Tags: python, numpy

I run the following in Python 2.7

```
import numpy
a = numpy.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=float, order='F')
print numpy.mean(a)
numpy.savetext('foo.txt', a)
```

and get this result

```
[me@foo bar]$ python f.py 
8.79658981512e-317
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 4, in <module>
    numpy.savetext('foo.txt', a)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'savetext'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 21):

It's `numpy.savetxt`, without the `e`.

Comment: Thanks!  Knew it had to be something really stupid.

Comment: If you install [IPython](http://ipython.org/), you'll get TAB-completion at the interactive prompt. So you could type `numpy.[TAB]` and see all the available functions. It can save you from this kind of error.